# How to check whether a process is daemon or not?

Tags: bash, shell, c, daemon

I have written a small daemon that starts at the boot time and does all the things perfectly like writing in the log file. But I want to know, how can we check whether that process is daemon or not?  My professor told me about a command
`ps -xj | grep daemon` (my file name is `daemon`), but I am not convinced about that as it shows unwanted information. Is there any shell command for that?

edit: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anything with the PPID of 1 is, for the most part, likely a daemon. But there are situations that can arise where processes can become children of 1 that are not technically daemons. So the methods I discuss below are to demonstrate how you'd go about determining if a PID is owned by 1, not necessarily that its a actual daemon.

#### For example

```
$ ps -xj
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
 8420  1211  1211  8420 pts/4     1211 S+    1000   0:01 ssh dufresne
    1  2276  2275  2275 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:48 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
 2196  2278  2278  2278 ?           -1 Ssl   1000   0:39 gnome-session
    1  2288  2278  2278 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00 dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session
    1  2289  2289  2289 ?           -1 Ssl   1000   6:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 4 --print-address 6 --session
    1  2358  2289  2289 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:01 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
```

The excerpt from Wikipedia can shed some light on things as well, but it too leaves things a little vague on how to actually determine if a process is a daemon or not.

*excerpt from Wikipedia*

> In a Unix environment, the parent process of a daemon is often, but
>   not always, the init process. A daemon is usually either created by a
>   process forking a child process and then immediately exiting, thus
>   causing init to adopt the child process, or by the init process
>   directly launching the daemon. In addition, a daemon launched by
>   forking and exiting typically must perform other operations, such as
>   dissociating the process from any controlling terminal (tty). Such
>   procedures are often implemented in various convenience routines such
>   as daemon(3) in Unix.

**NOTE:** on systems that make use of SystemD (Red Hat distros such as Fedora) there's typically no `init` process but instead this:

```
$ ps -j -1
  PID  PGID   SID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1     1     1 ?        Ss     0:42 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 20
```

That's the process with the PID 1.

On Debian/Ubuntu system's they'll have a process still named `init`:

```
$ ps -j -1
  PID  PGID   SID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1     1     1 ?        Ss     0:02 /sbin/init
```

#### So what's a daemon?

And here's the reason it can be tricky to determine if something is a daemon or not when its PPID is 1:

*A process can become a child of the init process, (**NOTE:** that `init` process is PID 1), when their parent is killed or disowns them, these processes are not necessarily daemons, but will still show up as having their PPID equal to 1*.

So to make the determination whether something is a daemon or not will likely require a battery of tests, and not simply looking to see if it's PPID is 1.

#### So where does that leave us?

To determine if something is a daemon you'll likely have to resort to a variety of tests such as:

- PPID 1?
- Has TTY attached?
- Is it a service? `sudo service ...`?
- Is it managed by Systemd, Upstart or SysV?
- Is it listening on a port?
- Is it writing to a log file? Syslog?

So we're having to resort to "duck typing" if it quacks, and swims, it's likely a duck, but even the above characteristics can fool you.

#### References

- [Daemon (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing))
- [Linux Daemon Writing HOWTO](http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html)

Comment: As you quoted: "In addition, a daemon launched by forking and exiting typically must perform other operations, such as dissociating the process from any controlling terminal (tty)." I'd include lack of a controlling TTY in my search criteria, as e.g. an *ssh* session is reparented to *init* when the *sshd* is restarted.

Comment: @SimonRichter - Good point. Added a paragraph about this too.

Comment: Having ppid=1 is not a reliable indicator of being a daemon. Plenty of processes that aren't daemons have survived their paren. Conversely, some daemon processes have a monitoring program or another process of the same daemon as their parent.

Comment: @Gilles - I've moved this A away from sounding so singular that PPID=1 is a good indicator of being a daemon. LMK what you think.

Comment: “Anything with the PPID of 1 is, for the most part, likely a daemon” is fundamentally wrong. For example, my window manager configuration tends to double fork when launching programs, so I have plenty of X applications whose PPID is 1. The converse actually works better on my machine, but that's because it's a desktop machine which doesn't tend to run supervised daemon processes — on a server machine you're likely to find many daemons whose PPID is a supervisor process.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to discern a regular process from a daemon process. A daemon can be started from anywhere, not just init. It is not necessary to double fork and detach from the terminal to be considered a daemon.

On GNOME systems, gnome-settings-daemon keeps its parent, logs to the parent's terminal, and does not have PID1 as its parent PID, yet it is still considered a daemon.

A daemon is simply a continuously running process. They are, therefore, impossible to identify with one command.

Now, if what you want is to know if your particular daemon is running, then take a gander at the `pgrep` command.

Also, change the name of your daemon, there is already a command called daemon that you may eventually conflict with.

Comment: Yes. I thought that pid of daemon is not always one because when I wrote my first daemon it was not attached to pid 1 process. Thank you.

Comment: no TTY attached should be considered as having a strong correlation (probably much greater than PPID 1) with being a daemon.

Comment: Yes, but no any process can have no terminal attached (e.g. cron jobs).